# \existsAlt command does not work with newpxmath

Tags: newtx

The `newtxmath` package has 2 variants of the there exists symbol and the forall symbol. While using the `newpxmath` package i see that there is only one and it looks quite ugly.

Can anyone help me out in getting a better thereexist and forall symbol with the `newpxmath` package.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Now? Is the package named `newtxmath` or `newpxmath`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer newpxmath has the problem.

Comment: As an aside, i would like to ask this question: We can scale the 2 packages newtx and newpx by giving the command \usepackage[scaled=1.5]{newtxtext}. Can such scaling be done with the "mathptmx" package?

Comment: From the documentation for `newtx`: As of version 1.5, the old `txfonts` versions of `\forall`, `\exists` and `\nexists` have been removed and the `Alt` versions substituted. Both `\forall` and `\forallAlt` generate ∀, and similarly with `\exists` and `\nexists`.”

Comment: Version 1.5 has been released on 2016/08/12

Comment: @egreg: How do i get the new version then?

Comment: @S.C. Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg Emm. Did manage to update my tex distribution from 2015 to 2016 but the problem still persists.

Comment: What problem? There is no alternate version for the symbol.

Comment: @egreg I mean as you said by version 1.5 of newtx package \existsAlt and \exists are basically the same. No! they aren't. But how do i check if my newtx version installed is 1.5 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 1.5 of NewTX, released on 2016/08/12, there is no alternate version of the quantifiers:

> As of version 1.5, the old `txfonts` versions of `\forall`, `\exists` and `\nexists` have been removed and the `Alt` versions substituted. Both `\forall` and `\forallAlt` generate ∀, and similarly with `\exists` and `\nexists`.

Indeed, the following document shows what's claimed in the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\verb|\exists\forall|: $\exists\forall$

\verb|\existsAlt\forallAlt|: $\existsAlt\forallAlt$

\texttt{\meaning\exists-\meaning\existsAlt}

\texttt{\meaning\forall-\meaning\forallAlt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I compile the same with TeX Live 2015, I get

[image]

The same document with `px` instead of `tx` produces what follows:

[image]

With TeX Live 2015, `\existsAlt` and `\forallAlt` produce errors. Removing them

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
\verb|\exists\forall|: $\exists\forall$
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

As you see, the ugly versions have been replaced in the current version of `newpxmath`.

Comment: Dear Greg, i understand this, and i also updated my Tex Distribution to 2016. But i am not sure, if that update comes with the latest version of newtx. Hence i think i am still facing the problem where \existsAlt command is not recognized by newpxmath. Is there anyway by which i can make sure, my newtx package is at its latest version?

Comment: @S.C. Just don't use the alt version, which used to be illegal with newpxmath anyhow. What's your TeX distribution?

Comment: LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.13) 14 JAN 2017 16:02                                                         Now if i use "\exists" command it still appears very very bold faced as I pointed out in the question.

Comment: @S.C. TeX Live/Debian always lags behind, unfortunately. Ensure it's fully updated with the package tools of your Linux box.

Comment: How do i ensure that? What is the other way of installing TeXLive other than TeXLive/Debian

Comment: @S.C. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu